# How to extract url, datetime, requestType, resourceUrl, status from string text in Java

Tags: java, regex, spring-boot, api, rest

I am doing this project where I have to read text from a file (that has multiple lines of text). Then I have to extract `url`, `datetime`, `requestType`, `resourceUrl` and `status` from each line and save it into the database columns respectively.

`127.0.0.1 - - [03/Dec/2020:05:48:05 +0000] "GET /web/test/explorer HTTP/1.1" 200 175842`

For example, for the above line, I have to fill database column with the values given below:

```
url             127.0.0.1
datatime        03/Dec/2020:05:48:05
requesttype     GET
resourceurl     /web/test/explorer HTTP/1.1
status          200
```

I know all of these can be extracted using regex but I don't know how to make a pattern to match these. Please suggest a pattern to extract all of these fields except `url` because I have done that one.
Here's the code I've written so far.

```
@Service
public class FileParser implements IFileParser{

    @Override
    public List<Request> parseFile(String fileData) throws Exception {
        
        List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();
        
        String lines[] = fileData.split("\\r?\\n");

        for(int i=0; i<lines.length; i++)
        {
            String line = lines[i];
            
            Request req = getRequestObject(line);
            requests.add(req);
            
        }
        
        return null;
    }
    
    private Request getRequestObject(String line)
    {
        Request request = new Request();
        
        request.setUrl(extractIP(line));
        request.setDateTime(extractDateTime(line));
        request.setRequestType(extractRequestType(line));
        request.setUrl(extractResourceUrl(line));
        request.setStatus(extractStatus(line));

        return request;
    }
    
    private String extractIP(String line)
    {
        String ip="";
        

        String IPADDRESS_PATTERN = 
                "(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(IPADDRESS_PATTERN);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            ip = matcher.group();
        } 
        
        return ip;
    }
    
    private String extractDateTime(String line)
    {
        String dateTime="";
        
        return dateTime;    
    }
    
    private String extractRequestType(String line)
    {
        String requestType="";
        
        return requestType; 
    }
    
    private String extractResourceUrl(String line)
    {
        String resourceUrl="";
        
        return resourceUrl;
    }
    
    private int extractStatus(String line)
    {
        int status=0;
        
        return status;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern:

```
((?:\d{1,3}\.?){4}).*(?=\[)\[([^+]+)[^\"]+\"(\w+)\s([^\"]+)\"\s(\d{3})
```

and extract the captured group.

Code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regex = "((?:\\d{1,3}\\.?){4}).*(?=\\[)\\[([^+]+)[^\\\"]+\\\"(\\w+)\\s([^\\\"]+)\\\"\\s(\\d{3})";
        String text = "127.0.0.1 - - [03/Dec/2020:05:48:05 +0000] \"GET /web/test/explorer HTTP/1.1\" 200 175842";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        while (matcher.find()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Group 1: 127.0.0.1
Group 2: 03/Dec/2020:05:48:05 
Group 3: GET
Group 4: /web/test/explorer HTTP/1.1
Group 5: 200
```